# Magento: Adding different text before both MSRP price and Group price 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, product

The new theme I've downloaded on our magento store displays only prices without any text descriptions before them.  I need to display both the MSRP and the price a certain customer group (wholesale) gets. I've searched and only found answers for how to add text before the MSRP price.

I basically need product pricing to display as such, MSRP: $XX.XX, Wholesale: $XX.XX.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code in:

```
app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```

Comment: I just need to know what code to add and where in app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

Comment: Where to add depends on how your price is displayed: tax included, excluded, both. Play around with it.